# Running a server in a simple pthread

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I'm trying to make my small multi client server run in a pthread so that the clients may receive and send data to the database.
At the moment I can telnet to the server, send a message to the server and it will be echoed back. I'd like to take the clients input and "use" it and send an answer to him.
The only way I can accomplish that is if I put the server in a thread I assume.
So I created a simple thread and called the server function from it but the server wont start for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
     void *startServer(void *)
    {

        cout << "Starting server\n";
        Server();
    }



    int main() 
    {

        pthread_t t;

        pthread_create(&t, NULL, &startServer, NULL);
        cout << "Hello";

        return 0;
    }
```

The only thing that shows after I run it is

> Hello

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't waiting for the thread, the main thread exits before the server thread can do anything, you need to do a pthread_join in the main thread, say, for example,  after printing hello.

```
pthread_join(t, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ immediately exits the process at the end of `main`, regardless of any other threads that are executing. As opposed to e.g. Java, which waits for all non-daemon threads to finish, IIRC.

If you want to wait till other threads are finished, you need to use `pthread_join`.